# Dynamically create new record based on the data inside a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

This is my current table which consist of responseid, variety, product, mixid and number of applications:

#Current table

| response_id | Variety | Product | MixID | ApplicationID | NumberofApplication |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Moddus | 1 | NULL | 3 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Cycocel | 1 | NULL | 3 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Proline | 1 | NULL | 3 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Firebid | 1 | NULL | 3 |

#expected table

| response_id | Variety | Product | MixID | ApplicationID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Moddus | 1 | 1 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Cycocel | 1 | 1 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Proline | 1 | 1 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Firebid | 1 | 1 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Moddus | 1 | 2 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Cycocel | 1 | 2 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Proline | 1 | 2 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Firebid | 1 | 2 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Moddus | 1 | 3 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Cycocel | 1 | 3 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Proline | 1 | 3 |
| mnmbaf | 776 | Firebid | 1 | 3 |

I am trying to create a query where we the table will create new rows based on the number of applications like below:

Lets say there are 3 number of applications, then there will be 12 rows created based on the 4 products.

This is my query as for now:

```
select ResponseID, Variety, Product, MixID, ApplicationID, NumberOfApplications
from #pattmp
where ResponseID = 'mnmbaf'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GENERATE_SERIES` function starting from SQL Server 2022, or in Azure.

```sql
SELECT
  pt.ResponseID,
  pt.Variety,
  pt.Product,
  pt.MixID,
  ApplicationID = g.value
FROM #pattmp pt
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1, pt.NumberOfApplications) g
WHERE pt.ResponseID = 'mnmbaf';
```

In older versions you can replace that with a join to a numbers table, or `APPLY` a [Number Series Function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1).